# We can't say anything about differentiability and continuity of a non decreasing function defined on an interval?

Tags: derivatives

[image: question link]

Will the answer be $d)none \ of \ these$ because we can't say anything without more information?

Comment: `we can't say anything without more information` That's correct.

Comment: The answer is (d); you should provide counterexamples for all of them to convince yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The floor function on $[0,2]$ is not continuous on $[0,2]$, not differentiable on $(0,2)$, and can't be inverted.  So the answer is $D$.